# Getting angularjs error in one server, where the same code works in another server perfectly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, console, gzip

I have one application, which has the UI as Angularjs. It calls the RestApis and get the Data and populate in UI. The same code works perfectly in one server, but it fails in different server. Here are the errors in the console.

[image]

The backend API gives proper result in CURL command.

Comment: can you share the code in ReportService.js ?

Comment: Added one call.

Comment: put the console.log(data) in error callback and provide the error you see on the console

Comment: Can you go to the network console, try the calls again and hit the call record in the network tab to see the error detail? if you can put some of the call code should be good as well.